# Using jettyRun in Gradle with Spring MVC app results in directory listing in browser

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, gradle

I have a simple Spring MVC application that is using Java-based configuration instead of XML. Whenever I run `gradle jettyRun` from the project directory, I get the following in the web browser:

[image: Directory Listing using Gradle jettyRun]

The application runs as expected when using Maven with `jetty-maven-plugin` and `mvn jetty:run`. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

The source code for the application is [here](https://github.com/caseyscarborough/spring-mvc-gradle-problem).

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but be aware that the `jetty` plugin that ships with Gradle is quite outdated (only supports Jetty 6 etc.). You'll likely fare better with the third-party `gretty` plugin.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Thanks for that. I just tried it with the `gretty` plugin and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser So is it safe to say that the `jetty` plugin (and Jetty 6) just may be too outdated to run this Spring app? If you'd like to create an answer I'd be happy to mark this as solved.

Comment: Jetty 6 does not implement Servlet 3.0 which is necessary in this case due to the way you are configuring your web application using `WebApplicationInitializer`. Prior versions require the existence of a `web.xml`.

Comment: @MarkVieira Thanks for clearing that up.